# Сложить значения label'ов по клику

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте. При клике на каждый div необходимо складывать их цены (текст из label). При втором клике - минусовать.
Вот мой код:

```js
$('.itemids').click(function() {
  // действия, которые будут выполнены при наступлении события...
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  var sum = 0;
  if (!clicks){
   $(this).css('background','rgba(26, 130, 64, 0.35)');
   sum += parseFloat($(this).find('.itemprice')[0].childNodes[0].data);
   console.log(sum);
   flag=1;
 }
 else{
  $(this).css('background','rgba(33, 52, 64, 0.35)');
  flag=0;
 }
 $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

Сейчас выводится только значение элемента, по которому кликнул. Но не складывается..

```html
<div id='242424215' class='itemids'>

 <div class='ok'>

  <img class="item" src="&&&&">
  <center><font>Item name</font></center>
  <center><label class="itemprice">35</label></center>
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
    var sum = 0;
    $('.itemids').click(function() {
      // действия, которые будут выполнены при наступлении события...
      var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
      var price = +$(this).find('.itemprice').text();
      console.log((clicks? "subtract" : "add") + " price " + price);
      if (!clicks){
     $(this).css('background','rgba(26, 130, 64, 0.35)');
     sum += price;
     flag = 1; //??
      } else {
        $(this).css('background','rgba(33, 52, 64, 0.35)');
     sum -= price;
        flag=0; //??
      }
      console.log(sum);
      $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='242424215' class='itemids'>
  <div class='ok'>
    <img class="item" src="&&&&">
      <center><font>Item name</font></center>
      <center><label class="itemprice">35</label></center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Пробовал - выводит NaN

Comment: После add price все равно NaN выводит..

Comment: @D.Joe Вот мне интересно, какой ответ Вы ожидаете? Я должен угадать Ваш html?

Comment: Извините.. Не думал, что тут в html дело. price он выводит, а вот sum - нет.
Сейчас добавлю html

Comment: Все, добавил часть html

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо! Вы спасли меня)

Comment: @D.Joe На здоровье. Успехов!

Comment: @D.Joe если ответ вас устраивает, не забудьте отметить его как подходящий (галочка слева от ответа)

Comment: Как раз не мог найти её))